# How can I Fetch Data from MySql DB using Hibernate as I am getting 'Null' value or Entity not Mapped while fetching?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am new to Hibernate and getting either error or null value when trying to fetch any row from my existing Table in MySQL database.

I have a Table named **'Customers'**, the table structure defined in sql is as below

```
`CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customerNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  .....
  .....
  `salesRepEmployeeNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creditLimit` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerNumber`),
  KEY `salesRepEmployeeNumber` (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employeeNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`
```

My **'Customer'** entity is defined as below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customers {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "customerNumber")
    private int customerNumber;

    ........
    ........
    @Column(name = "salesRepEmployeeNumber")
    private int salesRepEmployeeNumber;

    @Column(name = "creditLimit")
    private double creditLimit;

   
Getters and setters()
```

Here is my Reporitory through which I am trying to create the transactional methods. I have two methods, findbyId (to find using the Primary Key) and findAll(to get all rows).

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CustomersRepository {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;



    public Customers findbyId(int id){
       return em.find(Customers.class, id);

    }

    public List<Customers> findAll(){
        TypedQuery<Customers> query1= em.createQuery("Select c from Customer c", Customers.class);
        List<Customers> customersList = query1.getResultList();
        return customersList;
    }
}
```

Here is the main method.

```
package com.example.demo;


@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    CustomersRepository repository;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    

        logger.info("customer : {}",repository.findbyId(119));
        //logger.info("List of customer : {}",repository.findAll());

    }
}
```

when I am calling **findbyId**, I am getting **'null'**. when I am calling **findAll**, I am getting **Table not mapped** error.Here is the Log.

**Null for findbyId()**
Note : I have checked the data with this given **ID** is present in the table.

```
  HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2023-03-30 11:55:47.892  INFO 10412 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-03-30 11:55:47.908  INFO 10412 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-03-30 11:55:48.119  WARN 10412 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-03-30 11:55:48.751  INFO 10412 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-03-30 11:55:48.768  INFO 10412 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 8.008 seconds (JVM running for 8.957)
Hibernate: select customers0_.customer_number as customer1_0_0_, customers0_.address_line1 as address_2_0_0_, customers0_.address_line2 as address_3_0_0_, customers0_.city as city4_0_0_, customers0_.contact_first_name as contact_5_0_0_, customers0_.contact_last_name as contact_6_0_0_, customers0_.country as country7_0_0_, customers0_.credit_limit as credit_l8_0_0_, customers0_.customer_name as customer9_0_0_, customers0_.phone as phone10_0_0_, customers0_.postal_code as postal_11_0_0_, customers0_.sales_rep_employee_number as sales_r12_0_0_, customers0_.state as state13_0_0_ from customers customers0_ where customers0_.customer_number=?
2023-03-30 11:55:48.950  INFO 10412 --- [           main] ication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$296d79dd : customer : null
```

**
Customer not mapped for findAll()**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-03-30 12:10:01.682 ERROR 6532 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11-20230328.144451-6.jar:2.7.11-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11-20230328.144451-6.jar:2.7.11-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11-20230328.144451-6.jar:2.7.11-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11-20230328.144451-6.jar:2.7.11-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11-20230328.144451-6.jar:2.7.11-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Customer is not mapped [Select c from Customer c]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Customer is not mapped [Select c from Customer c]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374) ~[spring-orm-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235) ~[spring-orm-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at com.example.demo.reporitory.CustomersRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2a61318c.findAll(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.run(DemoApplication.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:768) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11-20230328.144451-6.jar:2.7.11-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Customer is not mapped [Select c from Customer c]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:757) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:848) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:315) ~[spring-orm-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.demo.reporitory.CustomersRepository.findAll(CustomersRepository.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.reporitory.CustomersRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$95f61396.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Customer is not mapped [Select c from Customer c]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:636) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Customer is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:334) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3782) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3671) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:746) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:602) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:339) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Here is my **application.properties** file.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classicmodels
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I am not sure why this is happening. I have checked Database is connected, I created another Entity and **modified ddl-auto=update to create Table in database from the entity and it got created**. I was also able to insert in that Table from my application, but can't fetch from existing tables. Please help.

Comment: `a) Select c from Customer c` -> `Select c from Customers c` As the exception says `Customer` is not mapped.  As per your entity, you are using the table `customers`. Also I do not think that `findbyId` will work.  The naming convention needs to be followed and should be `findById`

Comment: Hello, let me give you a suggestion - not actually to fix the issue but to make use of the full power of JPA repositories. All that methods like findById, findAll and many more don't need to be implemented. Properly defining a repository as extending the interface JpaRepository would be enough to get it all done by Spring Boot JPA.

Comment: @Mar-Z Yes I am aware of that, I was just trying this way. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You table's name is 'Customers' and you are querying with table 'Customer'

> "Select c from Customer c"

Answer (score 0):

your entity name and table name is Customers  and in your criteria query you are using Customer , which is causing issue.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Customer is not mapped [Select c from Customer c]

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "customers")
    public class Customers {
```

You can also try as follow for TypedQuery, after updating your entity class with Default constructor

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customers {

public Customers() {}
.....


   @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class CustomersRepository {
    
        @Autowired
        EntityManager em;
    
        public Customers findbyId(int id){
           return em.find(Customers.class, id);
    
        }
    
        public List<Customers> findAll(){
          CriteraiBuilder builder=em.getCriteriaBuilder();
          CriteriaQuery<Customers> query= builder.createQuery(Customers.class);
           Root<Customers> siteRoot = query.from(Customers.class);
           query.select(siteRoot);
           TypedQuery<Customers> query1= em.createQuery(query);
            List<Customers> customersList = query1.getResultList();
            return customersList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I rectified the entity name and also used query using CriteraiBuilder, and both are able to fetch table data. However there seems another problem in both cases, which is : 
My Java application is not fetching the table coloumns which are in Camel case, instead it is creating some new coloumns with Underscore case(which is because ddl-auto=update may be), but the thing is I used @Couloumn anotation to map the coloumn names with entity fields. 
Do I need to always use Underscore naming type for table coloumn names in database ?